# jHipster Release 8.0.0-rc.1: Unable to run gateway app

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I am getting following error:

*Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-20T17:33:24.634+05:30 ERROR 28508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint*

Here is my jdl for reference:

```
    application {
      config {
        enableTranslation true
        applicationType gateway
        serviceDiscoveryType consul
        languages [en, hi, te]
        nativeLanguage en
        packageName in.beze.pc
        testFrameworks [gatling, cucumber, protractor]
        websocket spring-websocket
        baseName pc
        serverPort 8080
        jhiPrefix sys
        prodDatabaseType postgresql
        devDatabaseType postgresql
        databaseType sql
        cacheProvider ehcache
        enableHibernateCache true
        authenticationType session
        buildTool gradle
        clientPackageManager npm
        clientFramework angularX
      }
      entities *
    }
    
    application {
      config {
        baseName masters
        applicationType microservice
        packageName in.beze.masters
        serviceDiscoveryType consul
        authenticationType session
        prodDatabaseType postgresql
        devDatabaseType postgresql
        databaseType sql
        buildTool gradle
        serverPort 8081
        skipUserManagement true
        cacheProvider ehcache
        enableHibernateCache true
        websocket spring-websocket
      }
      entities Attachment, ContentType, Equipment, EquipmentType, FacilityType, FacilityGroupType, FacilityGroup, Facility, FacilityHistory, FacilityUser, FacilityAttachment, FacilityEquipment, FrequencyType, Frequency, Gender, JobSandbox, Language, Party, Permission, PermissionAuthority, ProductStoreType, ProductStore, ProductStoreFacility, ProductStoreUserGroup, Responsibility, RoleType, Scheduler, StatusCategory, Status, StatusValidChange, UserRole, UserGroup, UserGroupAuthority, UserGroupMember, Uom, UomType, UserAttachment, SystemParameters, QRCode, QRCodeType, QRCodeAttachment, Product, ProductType, ProductCategoryType, ProductCategory, ProductCategoryMember, Stage, ProductSpecGroup, ProductSpec, ProductSpecItem, StabilityCondition, StabilityConditionAttachment
    }

application {
  config {
    baseName stability
    applicationType microservice
    packageName in.beze.stability
    serviceDiscoveryType consul
    authenticationType session
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    devDatabaseType postgresql
    databaseType sql
    buildTool gradle
    serverPort 8082
    skipUserManagement true
    cacheProvider ehcache
    enableHibernateCache true
    websocket spring-websocket
  }
  entities StAttachment, StContentType, AnalysisType, SpEquipment, SsEquipment, SpProductSpec, StabilityProgramme, StabilityAttachment, SampleType, StabilitySample, SampleResult, SampleAttachment, SampleResultAttachment, EquipmentSc
}
```

I have tried different java versions and couldn't get it up and running.

Comment: You should post an issue on github. Probably a bug about websockets, have you tried removing websocket from your JDL?

Comment: Not sure if its a bug or my understanding problem. I removed web socket from the jdl and now I get different problem in gateway application build. reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay